# .htaccess and dns redirecting windows hosted .com website to my linux .co.za wordpress website

Tags: linux, wordpress, windows, .htaccess, dns

Hi so basically I am trying to redirect www.blackearthconsulting.com which is hosted on a windows server to www.blackearthconsulting.co.za which is on a linux server.

I have Changed the dns on the .com to point to 197.242.144.191 which is the dns on the .co.za.

I have also edit the .htaccess file on both .com and .co.za

bellow is the .co.za

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} blackearthconsulting\.co.za
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.blackearthconsulting.com/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

bellow is the .com

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} blackearthconsulting\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.blackearthconsulting.co.za/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Please can someone let me know what is wrong?

Comment: What does the DNS have to do with the rewriting?

Comment: So your .com is rewriting to .co.za, and .co.za is rewriting to .com? Unless you _want_ to create a loop, that doesn’t make sense.

Comment: You should only need to redirect .com to .co.za.  So you shouldn't need any redirects on the co.za side.  I would leave the DNS unchanged and simply redirect from .com

Comment: Alright, I changed the .co.za htacess to not run anything in terms of rewriting anything but it still isn't getting the .com to redirect

Comment: Probably because you pointed the A record to the co.za. So it is now looking for the account at 197.242.144.191, which does not exist. If you change the A record back, it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks so I changed the A record back. It seems to be redirecting just to my hosting company and not the url it needs to so ill make a few modifictions to the .htaccess file. Thanks a million dude!

Comment: I guess sometimes over complicating things is where the issue lies.

Comment: From the Afrihost CPanel, you should be able to do a domain redirect. If all else fails, their support is pretty quick.

Comment: For your regex, `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} blackearthconsulting\.co.za`, you escaped only the first dot, but forgot the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Probably because you pointed the *A record* to the co.za. So it is now looking for the account at 197.242.144.191, which does not exist. If you change the A record back, it should work fine. – @[Und3rTow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3055401/und3rtow)"

Remove all changes from the .co.za
change the dns back to the original dns

revise the .htaccess file on the .com server